# How to animate exit with react-transition-group

Tags: reactjs, react-transition-group

I am using react-transition-group to create a modal that pops into view.

```
const AnimatedModal: SFC<AnimatedModalProps> = (props: AnimatedModalProps) => (
<CSSTransition in={props.showWindow} unmountOnExit key={1} classNames={'modal-fade'} timeout={300}>
    <BaseModal onCloseHandler={props.onCloseHandler} showWindow={props.showWindow}>
        <CSSTransition
            in={props.showWindow}
            key={2}
            unmountOnExit
            classNames={props.animationClassNames}
            timeout={300}
        >
            <ModalPanel onCloseHandler={props.onCloseHandler}>{props.children}</ModalPanel>
        </CSSTransition>
    </BaseModal>
</CSSTransition>
```

);

However I am very confused on how to get this to animate out on exit. Since as soon as I sed props.showWindow = false. It destroys the whole component without giving it time to animate out.

Is there some what to do this by nesting this in a TransitionGroup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [childFactory](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition-group#TransitionGroup-prop-childFactory) prop of the `<TransitionGroup>` component. I haven't tried it with nested `<CSSTransition>` components, but it can normally be used like so:

```
 <TransitionGroup
     childFactory={child => React.cloneElement(child)}
  >
    <CSSTransition 
      in={props.showWindow} 
      timeout={400} 
      classNames={classes.exitTransition}
    >
      <ChildComponent/>
    </CSSTransition>
  </TransitionGroup>
```